# Java Keytool does not accepts the "yes" word and start again and again

Tags: java, certificate, keytool

I'm trying to generate a certificate for an Android app with the following command:

```
keytool -genkey -v -keystore my_key.keystore
-alias my_alias -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000
```

When I finish the last question, the

> "Its correct [no]: "

message apperars. If I write YES, keytool ignores my answer and starts from the beginning again.

I'm on Windows 7 and  jdk1.7.0_79.

[See this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k0s7U.png)

Any idea about it?

Comment: I have never used keytool with a locale other than en_us (as it would appear you are doing), but is it possible it is looking for 'yes' in your locale?

Comment: OH MY GOD, you're right ... keytool is waiting for the word "SI", that is "yes" ... thank you.

Comment: I was going to suggest "si", but I thought you might think that I was joking, so I figured I'd offer a less assuming suggestion. I answered for posterity.

Answer (score 12):

It would appear that you are using a locale other than `en_us`, perhaps `es_XX`?

As such, keytool is most likely looking for "yes" in your locale ("si" in this case).